# Why do photons in the Casimir effect get destroyed when they collide with each other?

Tags: photons, casimir-effect

Shouldn't these photons create a stronger photon when they collide? If you shine a light at another light it gets stronger not destroyed. Why is it different in the Casimir effect case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to be careful in quantum electrodynamics to disntiguish between *photons*, real [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) on mass shell, and [virtual photons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) , as in this simple feynman diagram of electron-electron scattering:

[image: ee]

The Casimir effect is more complicated, but the fields that give the effect are represented by *virtual photons*.

> [When this field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Physical_properties) is instead studied using the quantum electrodynamic vacuum, it is seen that the plates do affect the virtual photons which constitute the field, and generate a net force – either an attraction or a repulsion depending on the specific arrangement of the two plates.

So the virtual photons do not interact the way real photons do.

There are a number of models for the casimir effect that do not use pure QED , but use the concept of photons, creating a confusion. [Photon photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) interactions are very improbable in QED .

Comment: Really nice answer.